# Cómo implementar esta validación a una fecha?

Tags: java, spring-boot, busqueda-rango-de-fechas

Tengo este caso de error ingreso una fecha equivocada 13/07/20222 un dígito de mas... y estoy usando un SimpleDateFormat "dd/mm/yyyy" como puedo hacer para restringir o evitar este error... gracias de ante mano

Comment: Hay muchas formas, seguramente. Pero no sabemos cómo recibes, transmites y procesas ese dato (no hay código en la pregunta), así que no hay cómo proveer respuestas puntuales. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.